# Struts2 redirect with persistent parameters

Tags: struts2

I am trying to implement a Post Redirect Get pattern for my web application using struts2. The problem I am having is that whenever I redirect to either the jsp or to an action which then returns the same jsp I lose the parameters from the original request that the jsp needs to display.

Is there any way to dynamically pass every parameter from the original request onto the redirected action or jsp?

Thank you,

Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [scope interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html).

Alternatively, use the same technique to create a simple flash interceptor that requires less configuration.

(Or keep/remove it in session manually, or ignore that it's there if it's not that big.)

Comment: I'm hesitant to use the session any more than I have to as I'm developing for a clustered environment...do you know if these take clustering into account? Quick googling didn't provide anything promising but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Session is session; replication is a container issue, not framework-all flash scope solutions use the session, it's the only user-specific place to put stuff across requests unless you specifically copy everything into a new request-which you can certainly do also.

Comment: That sounds like what I would prefer to do. Sorry for my lack of knowledge about struts internal workings, but do you know of a good article I could look at regarding copying everything into a new request?

Comment: @bwags It depends on what you're really trying to do. If it's just a few simple params, use a [dynamic result definition](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/parameters-in-configuration-results.html). If it's more complex than that allows, you'll need either go back to using the session (don't know exactly what your concern really is), or re-retrieve an object by ID, etc.